# Setting Action Visibility using multiple field values

Tags: lightning, custom-actions

Does Salesforce lightning filtering allow action visibility to be set using a single filter with multiple field values yet? Cannot create a formula field to handle this due to number of fields and maint. My need is to show an action button on the highlights panel only for (2) unique task record types. Tried several string formats using single/double quotes, commas, semicolon,.... nothing seems to allow for this. Hopefully there is else I add multiple logic conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same field in multiple filter with different values (single value only) and use the Custom Filter logic to handle your requirement.

For Example. Case Object having 3 available record types and I want to display the button on any 2 record types only.

[image]